# android:FrameLayout doesn't put a layout on its bottom

Tags: android, android-framelayout

Hello Android programmers,

I was trying to make a screen that has an EditText and bottom button bar with Framelayout so that my bottom button bar will remain on the bottom no matter how big the edittext will be by the user because FrameLayout makes my bottom button bar positioned on the top of the screen. Below is my code.

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello" />

        <EditText android:id="@+id/tm_et_date_year" android:layout_width="120px" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tm_ll_buttons" android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="bottom">
            <Button android:id="@+id/tm_btn_save" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Save" android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/tm_btn_cancel" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Cancel" android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

However, when I finished coding, the bottom button bar suddenly appeared on the TOP not the BOTTOM like below.

`http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/6374/71485552.jpg`

I searched this issue but couldn't find any good articles that can help me so now ask you for advice. If anyone knows how to solve this problem, could you help me?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try :

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
```

on your `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Hello slukian, thanks for your answer. I already tried that but unfortunately it didn't work. Could you give me another solution?

Comment: Oops. Sorry slukian, when I tried it there was a syntax error. So, now I see your method worked well!! Thank you!!

Comment: Hello alextsc, as you mentioned it worked fine for me too. I just had a syntax error when I first tried, and that was why I thought it didn't work. Thanks for your effort since you copied all of my code and tried it! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Can u please help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16364195/top-and-bottom-images-overlay-on-imageview-issue/16364588#comment23447984_16364588

Comment: @SpryTechies Please post a new question providing all the details about your layouts.