# Top and bottom images overlay on imageview Issue

Tags: android, android-layout, overlay, android-framelayout

I want to make my layout like this as per below picture. this image i am able to see in iphone devices.

Here i used frame layout to achieve make overlays of top and bottom image bar on imageview but after using frame layout i can only able to see top imagebar overlay not bottom image bar? why its happens?

Forgot about the content of top and bottom iamge bar.. i am focusing to achieve this functionality.

Please make me correct if i am wrong in my code.

xml file code :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/top_bar"
        layout="@layout/item_below_image_bar"
        android:gravity="top" />

    <it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.ImageViewTouch
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/descr_image"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/below_bar"
        layout="@layout/item_below_image_bar"
        android:gravity="bottom" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: mind to post your codes on `item_below_image_bar` and `item_below_image_bar`? Anyway, try setting `android:layout_gravity="top"` or `android:layout_gravity="bottom"`. Setting gravity doesn't really affect anything here.

Comment: I already added gravity of both layouts. its does not work

Comment: have you tried re ordering the views? I think your image view needs to be at the bottom in the xml

Comment: Is there a typo in codes you posted? because both includes are using item_below_image_bar layout

Comment: @ChorWaiChun for about the include layout..Assume that are same as of now .. in top and bottom.

Comment: @Eluvatar but i want to make in center. I dnt want to be image view at bottom. using this layout i am achieving like this displays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

per android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)

> Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top.

so you need to arrange your layout as follows

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.ImageViewTouch
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/descr_image"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />   

    <include
        android:id="@+id/top_bar"
        layout="@layout/item_below_image_bar"
        android:gravity="top" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/below_bar"
        layout="@layout/item_below_image_bar"
        android:gravity="bottom" />

</FrameLayout>
```

in this case the actual location of the view is not determined by the order that the views are declared in the xml. For a linear layout this would be true however not so with the FrameLayout, in a framelayout the location is determined by gravity so your views will still be placed in the correct locations and they will be loaded in order they were declared, so first is the image view, then the first include is placed on top of that, then the second include is placed on top of that (however in this case they dont intersect so it doesn't matter).

edit2: after chatting with sam we were able to figure out the problem here's our solution

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:id="@+id/greenImage"
            android:src="#2dff3d"/>


    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
            >

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="My Label"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="14dp">

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="My Label"
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

note the usage of layout_gravity as apposed to just gravity.

Comment: In my code and your code the difference is only just ordering. i think it will not change the things.. let me check.. any ways thanks for your reply

Comment: yes the order of the views is the only difference, but you want the image view to be on the bottom of the stack hence the difference.

Comment: I want layout as like first image which i already put in my question body

Comment: I used same like you suggested but its not working. this time i am not able to see that top image bar also. only imageview is there nothing else

Comment: oh oops, sorry flip that around then, declare the image view first sorry. edited my answer

Comment: here's an example I whipped up it works fine for me, http://puu.sh/2M7bQ.png, http://pastebin.com/C513WcZZ

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29387/discussion-between-sam-k-and-eluvatar)

Comment: Have u used same code? which u posted there can u please give me your code?